# MySQL how to get count of instances across columns as well as rows?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 10 columns in it like so, showing an item that was bought in a virtual shop, and the currency that was used to buy it:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| soldfor_1 | soldfor_2 | soldfor_3 | soldfor_4 | soldfor_5 | soldfor_6 | soldfor_7 | soldfor_8 | soldfor_9 | soldfor_10 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| Gold      | Gold      | Gold      | Silver    | Silver    |           | Bronze    | Gold      |           | Gold       |
| Gold      | Gold      | Gold      | Gold      | Gold      | Gold      |           |           |           |            |
| Bronze    | Silver    | Silver    | Silver    | Gold      | Gold      | Silver    | Bronze    | Gold      |            |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to query this selection so that I create a list of the three different currencies used (gold, silver and bronze), ordered by the number of times the currency occurs in any of the columns AND any of the rows.

For example's sake, the output I want from the query would look like this:

```
Gold 14
Silver 6
Bronze 3
```

It has counted the amount of times that the three different types of currency occur in both columns and rows, and it has then put them into a list ordered by this amount. Then it has appended the number of times next to each type of currency.

However I'm not having any luck. What I've been able to do so far is to count the number of times that the item occurs on any row, sort of - the query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    soldfor_1, 
    soldfor_2, 
    soldfor_3, 
    soldfor_4, 
    soldfor_5, 
    soldfor_6, 
    soldfor_7, 
    soldfor_8, 
    soldfor_9, 
    soldfor_10, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM phpbb_topics 
WHERE 
   forum_id=16 
   AND sold=1 
GROUP BY topic_title 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

But this only gives me an ordered list of the the currencies as they occur in ROWS only. I want it to take into account COLUMNS also.

Does anyone have any idea of what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot, which in MySQL uses `union all`:

```
select soldfor, count(*)
from ((select soldfor_1 as soldfor from phpbb_topics) union all
      (select soldfor_2 as soldfor from phpbb_topics) union all
      . . .
      (select soldfor_10 as soldfor from phpbb_topics)
     ) s
group by soldfor;
```

Normally, it is a sign of a bad data model when you have multiple columns distinguished only by number.  A more reasonable data model would have a table with one row per column value.